"Error: crypto.getRandomValues must be defined" on React Native Expo using @Solana/Web3.js
Im building a solwallet using Solana/Web3/js, and i need to create a wallet account, so my approach is generate mnemonic so it can become seeds for a keypair, so it'll be the recovery phrase if needed.
heres my approach code
export default async function generateKeypair() {
  const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();

  // Convert mnemonic to binary seed
  const seedBytes = await mnemonicToSeed(mnemonic);

  const keypair = Keypair.fromSeed(seedBytes);

  const privateKey = keypair.secretKey;
  const publicKey = keypair.publicKey;

  // Convert the private key to a base58 string
  const base58PrivateKey = bs58.encode(privateKey);

  // Convert into Hex string
  const privateKeyHex = Array.from(privateKey)
    .map((byte) => byte.toString(16).padStart(2, '0'))
    .join('');

  return { base58PrivateKey, privateKeyHex, publicKey, mnemonic };
}

But i got an error which from node_modules/react-native it says

Error creating wallet: [Error: crypto.getRandomValues must be defined]

when I debug it one by one, the cause is from
const mnemonic = bip39.generateMnemonic();
anyway i call it like this
export default function createWallet() {
  const handleCreateWallet = async () => {
    try {
      const { mnemonic } = await generateKeypair();

      // console.log(' Base 58 Private Key:', base58PrivateKey);
      // console.log(' Hex Private Key:', privateKeyHex);
      // console.log('Public Key:', publicKey);
      console.log('Mnemonics:', mnemonic);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error creating wallet:', error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Generate Wallet" onPress={handleCreateWallet} />
    </View>
  );
}

so it got me stuck in here, I cant generate a key pair from mnemonics
ps. im new in this web3 thing, if anyone have different approach or logic so please enlighten me

I believe this is an issue of not having crypto polyfills available in react-native contexts. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61169746/crypto-getrandomvalues-not-supported for some more information and solutions
